# Jquery fancybox conflicts with jquery tabs

Tags: fancybox

I am having huge problem implementing jquery fancy box. In the page where I want to include it I am using jquery tabs and I think it is conflicting with fancybox. 
I am getting this error: $("#various1").fancybox is not a function
I checked couple of times and it is not including path problem, just conflict problem. I've got the following scripts included in the `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/primary.js"></script>    

<link href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />    
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');</script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#various1").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none'
    });
});
</script>
```

I tried adding     jQuery.noConflict();    like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();    
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#various1").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none'
    });
});
</script>
```

but this didn't solve the problem. After that I added jQuery.noConflict();    in all files included in the main page and still same error: 
    $("#various1").fancybox is not a function and after I expand it I can see this:
f(b=Document testfancybox.php, f=[function()])
f(a=undefined) in line 2 file http://...js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
If I exclude one of the files included in the main page the error goes away. In that file I have jquery tabs and as I said adding noconflict function doesn't help.
How to debug this error?

Comment: you seen to be loading jQuery three times when you only need a single instance of it (preferably the latest version)

Answer (score 2):

The answer for this: Just rename

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$("#various1").fancybox({
```

to

```
jquery(document).ready(function() {    
jquery("#various1").fancybox({
```

and than add noconflict function jQuery.noConflict(); to all place where it uses $ function and the problem will be solved..